# placing an element or a box on the bottom of window using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using flexbox, how can I  move the `.bottom` div to the bottom of the window? The `flex-direction` of the `.boxContainer` is `column` so that everything can be moved vertically. I tried `align-self: flex-end` and `align-self: baseline` but both just pushed the box horizontally, not vertically. I hope someone could help me fix this.

```css
.boxContainer {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background: peachpuff;

 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.center {
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
 background: honeydew;
}

.bottom {
 width: 300px;
 height: 50px;
 background: cyan;
 align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContainer">
 <div class="center"></div>
 <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `align-items`, `align-self` and `align-content` work along the *cross axis*. `justify-content` works along the *main axis*. When you're in `flex-direction: column`, the cross axis is horizontal and the main axis is vertical. That's why `align-self` is moving your item left/right. Use `justify-content` or `auto` margins instead. See duplicate for details.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the justify-content to space-between and it should do the trick for you.

In case, you dont need the center div to be pushed up, You could set the margin-top auto to both center and bottom divs.

```css
.boxContainer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.center {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: honeydew;
  margin-top: auto;
}
.bottom {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: cyan;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContainer">
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the `.center` div is being pushed to the very top

Comment: Updated the snippet to not push the center div up.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `align-self: flex-end;` with `align-content: flex-end;` add `margin-top: auto` on `.bottom` class.

```css
.boxContainer {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background: peachpuff;

 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.center {
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
 background: honeydew;
}

.bottom {
 width: 300px;
 height: 50px;
 background: cyan;
 align-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContainer">
 <div class="center"></div>
 <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it just sticked to the `.center` div

Comment: Thanks for your help